# Pickle borrar un dato en python

Tags: python, archivo, diseño-de-clases, pickle

Buen día, es la primera vez que trabajo con la librería pickle en Python y me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de borrar un registro ya creado, ya sea por el nombre del producto o por un id. Ya intente de varías maneras de crear una función que me permita borrar un registro, no se si alguien me pudiese ayudar u orientar.
En caso de que no se pudiera también me gustaría saberlo para buscar otras alternativas para hacer un programa, muchas gracias

```
import pickle

class producto:
    def __init__(self,nombre,precioCompra, precioVenta, Cantidad):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.precioCompra = precioCompra
        self.PrecioVenta = precioVenta + (precioCompra +(precioCompra*.30))
        self.Cantidad = Cantidad
        print("Se guardo el producto", self.nombre)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} {} {}".format(self.nombre,self.precioCompra,self.PrecioVenta, self.Cantidad)

class ListaProducto:
    productos=[]
    def __init__(self):
        listadeProductos = open("InventarioTienda",'ab+')
        listadeProductos.seek(0)
        try:
            self.productos = pickle.load(listadeProductos)
            print("Se cargaron {} productos del inventario".format(len(self.productos)))
        except:           
            print("No hay productos en el inventario")
        finally:
            listadeProductos.close()
            del(listadeProductos)

    def agregarProducto(self,p):
        self.productos.append(p)
        self.GuadarProductosFichero()

    def mostarProductos(self):
        for p in self.productos:
            print(p)

    def GuadarProductosFichero(self):
        listadeProductos = open("InventarioTienda", "wb")
        pickle.dump(self.productos, listadeProductos)
        listadeProductos.close()
        del(listadeProductos)

    def MostrarProductosFichero(self):
        print("Estos son los productos en inventario: ")
        for i in self.productos:
            print(i)





Milista =ListaProducto()

productos1 = producto("papas",10,0,50)
productos1 = producto("sal",2,0,100)

Milista.agregarProducto(productos1)
Milista.MostrarProductosFichero()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es construir un metodo que quite un elemento de la lista `self.productos` y que luego guarde una versión actualizada del pickle. Así el problema se reduce a manipular la lista para quitar el elemento, ya sea por nombre o por indice, y luego llamar al metodo `self.GuadarProductosFichero()` para guardar una versión del pickle sin el elemento que se quiere quitar.

Aqui te entrego unos metodos para lograrlo para la clase `ListaProducto`:

```py
def quitar_producto_por_nombre(self, nombre_producto):
    self.productos = [producto for self.productos if producto.nombre != nombre_producto] 
    self.GuadarProductosFichero()

def quitar_producto_por_indice(self, indice_producto):
    del self.productos[indice_producto]
    self.GuadarProductosFichero()
```

Si te fijas, el metodo `quitar_producto_por_nombre` requiere iterar la lista para encontrar los productos con nombre igual a `nombre_producto` esto puede ser ineficiente si la lista de productos es muy grande. La solución para esto es utilizar otra estructura de datos que permita acceder directamente a los elementos como un diccionario.

Por otro lado, `quitar_producto_por_indice` permite acceder al elemento directamente para quitar por lo que es más eficiente que quitarlo por nombre.